# Passing variable from JavaScript to PHP without using Query String

Tags: javascript, php

How can I pass the longitude and latitude from the below code to my PHP code?

```
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    document.getElementById("getlat").value = position.coords.latitude;
    document.getElementById("getlon").value = position.coords.longitude;
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="hidden" id="getlat" name="getlat" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['polat']; ?>" /> 
<input type="hidden" id="getlon" name="getlon" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['polon']; ?>" />
```

PHP Code

```
$lat = '-27.486204'; // Should get latitude from JS here.
$long = '152.994962'; // Should get longitude from JS here.

    mysqli_query("SELECT * From `table_nme` where `latitude`='.$lat.' AND `longitude`='.$long.'");
```

I know how to do this in Query String Process but I need it without Query String Process.

Comment: Send an ajax request? **Remember:** PHP runs LONGGGGGG before the client side code does (javascript in this instance)

Comment: AJAX is the best bet in your case, @lock.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following Javascript code:

```
var lat = position.coords.latitude,
    long = position.coords.laongitude,
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('GET', 'http://url-to-server.xxx/page.php?polat=' + lat + '&polong=' + long, false);
xhr.send();

var result = xhr.responseText;
```